# Creating a FileStream that honours the "Append Data" NTFS privilege

Tags: .net, batch-file, winapi, vbscript, ntfs

Consider an NTFS folder that has the explicit permissions *Create Files / Write Data* applied onto *This Folder Only*, and *Create Folders / Append Data* applied onto *Files Only* (and Read Attributes, because I understand that to be necessary).

```
> icacls x:\pathto\folder
x:\pathto\folder CONTOSO\Domain Users:(CI)(S,WD)
                 CONTOSO\Domain Users:(OI)(IO)(S,AD,REA,RA)
                 BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
                 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
```

*In theory*, this should allow a user to create a file if it doesn't exist, and append to a file if it does exist, but not otherwise overwrite or truncate the contents of the file, nor delete it.

Now, given that, how does one actually *open* that file for appending?

I've tried simple command-line/batch redirection:

```
> echo foo >> x:\pathto\folder\thefile.txt
> echo foo >> x:\pathto\folder\thefile.txt
Access denied.
```

...and VBScript

```
Dim fso : Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim stream : Set stream = fso.OpenTextFile("x:\pathto\folder\thefile.txt", 8, True, 0)  ' 8-ForAppending
stream.WriteLine("foo")
-----
> cscript writefoo.vbs //nologo //e:vbs
> cscript writefoo.vbs //nologo //e:vbs
Microsoft VBScript Runtime Error(2, 14): Permission denied
```

...and .NET (via PowerShell)

```
> (1..2) | %{
>   Write-Host $_
>   $f = [IO.File]::AppendText('x:\pathto\folder\thefile.txt')
>   $f.WriteLine("foo")
>   $f.Dispose()
> }
1
2
Exception calling "AppendText" with "1" argument(s): Access to the path "x:\pathto\folder\thefile.txt" is denied.
```

...and another .NET approach (again via PowerShell)

```
> (1..2) | %{
>   Write-Host $_
>   $f = [IO.File]::Open('x:\pathto\folder\thefile.txt', [IO.FileMode]::Append, [IO.FileAccess]::Write, [IO.FileShare]::None)
>   $f = New-Object IO.StreamWriter -Arg $f
>   $f.WriteLine("foo")
>   $f.Dispose()
> }
1
2
Exception calling "Open" with "4" argument(s): Access to the path "x:\pathto\folder\thefile.txt" is denied.
```

In all cases, with Sysinternals Procmon running, I can see that the underlying `CreateFile` is always made requesting `Generic Write` for its permissions.

If I understand correctly, `Generic Write` means Win32's `FILE_GENERIC_WRITE`, which is a bitflag combination of `FILE_APPEND_DATA | FILE_WRITE_DATA` (and others) which would require *Create Files / Write Data* on the *file* as well as the *directory*.

However, if I place *Create Files / Write Data* on the file, then files are no longer append-only -- they can't be deleted and re-written, but they *can* be *truncated* and rewritten -- which defeats the purpose.

So what mechanisms are available to me to open the file really, *really* for Append only?

Comment: write attributes permmission. may be…https://superuser.com/questions/745923/ntfs-permissions-create-files-and-folder-but-prevent-deletion-and-modification or 
https://www.itprotoday.com/strategy/ntfs-secrets

Comment: The .h file says only local files and doesn't mention network files. For a file object, the right to append data to the file. (For local files, write operations will not overwrite existing data if this flag is specified without FILE_WRITE_DATA.) For a directory object, the right to create a subdirectory (FILE_ADD_SUBDIRECTORY).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, at least for PowerShell/.NET.  The .NET `FileStream` object offers a constructor which takes a `FileSystemRights` enum parameter, which lets you explicitly limit the underlying `CreateFile` call not to require `Generic Write`.

```
> (1..3) | %{
>   Write-Host $_
>   $f = New-Object -TypeName 'IO.FileStream' `
>                   -ArgumentList $private:file,`
>                                 ([IO.FileMode]::Append),`
>                                 ([Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::AppendData),`
>                                 ([IO.FileShare]::Read),`
>                                 4KB,`
>                                 ([IO.FileOptions]::None)
>   $f = New-Object -TypeName 'IO.StreamWriter' `
>                   -ArgumentList $f
>   $f.WriteLine("foo")
>   $f.Dispose()
> }
1
2
3
```

No options that I know of for VBScript or Batch (beyond [Drake's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56423674/415523) of rolling one's own COM type or append.exe, which calls `CreateFile` directly via C++/Win32).

Answer (score 3):

You really should only open files with Append Data. 
[Difference between FILE_WRITE_DATA and FILE_APPEND_DATA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093571/difference-between-file-write-data-and-file-append-data).

`echo` and other methods cannot append data with only Append Data access(There are other complicated access inside. according to your test), but why not create a "Append" command(like `echo`) directly using `CreateFile`? Access Privileges can be strictly controlled with `CreateFile`.

Append.cpp:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3)
        return 0;
    //cout << argv[1] << "," << argv[2] << endl;
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(argv[2], FILE_APPEND_DATA, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    WriteFile(hFile,argv[1],strlen(argv[1]),0,0);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

Then copy the Append.exe to the folder where you want to execute `echo` or  "C:\Windows\System32". Use the it like command:

```
Append foo x:\pathto\folder\thefile.txt
```