# Atomic append string to file in Windows using Java

Tags: java, windows, multithreading, scala

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032482/is-appending-to-a-file-atomic-with-windows-ntfs), small file appends on Windows are atomic.

I am trying to leverage this in Scala / Java to avoid locking when appending a small int to a file.

I am finding that writes using `FileOutputStream(..., true)` from multiple threads are being interleaved, even though the question linked above suggests that they should be atomic.

A test harness for this in Scala can be found [on my github](https://github.com/RichardBradley/scalac-scoverage-plugin/commit/05920e764e0b5a423097a71ddcda4692d53bb275)

The key code is:

```
def invoked(id: Int, path: String) = {
  val writer = new FileOutputStream(path, true)
  val bytes = (id.toString + ';').getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset())
  writer.write(bytes)
  writer.close()
}
```

... I was hoping that "invoked" would be thread-safe without locking.

The same Java/Scala code achieves atomic file appends on Linux (as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154446) small file appends are atomic on POSIX), so the difference seems to be in the native implementations of `FileOutputStream`.

Perhaps `FileOutputStream` is not passing the correct flags to Windows? Does anyone know how to make this work? Will I have to write a JNI DLL to get this to work, or is there a way I can do this with Java's standard libraries?

Comment: I think that Windows and POSIX both offer this guarantee, which is enough OSes for me. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154446

Comment: The safest way to do what you want to do is to have your producer threads "write" to a single consumer thread. The single consumer thread handles the actual file writing.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc that would be a decent approach, yes. However, if the O/S provides atomic file writes (and it does claim to), then it would be more efficient to take advantage of that. I have already implemented a more conventional workaround. This question is about how to make the atomic file writes approach work in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write operation behavior depends on file opening flags. On Windows you need to use FILE_APPEND_DATA flag or use the special constants to achieve append. Posix require O_APPEND flag. Although Java has bool value for append parameter looking into its source code following comment explains [why it does not work](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/nio/ch/FileDispatcherImpl.java#FileDispatcherImpl).

```
FileDispatcherImpl(boolean append) {
    /* append is ignored */
}
```