# Logging to a file in Node.js : Is it safe with clusters?

Tags: multithreading, node.js, logging, conflict

If I have 4, 8 or more threads & clusters on one box running this code, can there be resource contention over log files / file writers? If so, could you post an example that illustrates? So far all the testing I've done seems to indicate that write data won't get interwoven and won't get thrown away, but I am not 100% convinced

Thanks!

```
var errLog = fs.createWriteStream(... + '/error.log');
GLOBAL.dbLog = fs.createWriteStream(... + '/db.log');
```

Comment: Did you do any testing with chunks larger than the size of your platform's `PIPE_BUF` limit? (`/usr/include/linux/limits.h` on my system defines `PIPE_BUF` to `4096` bytes. Your platform may be different.)

Comment: I did not. Are you saying this could affect things? And if so, what is the solution?

Comment: I have a suspicion that it _might_ influence the results, but that's just a suspicion.

Comment: I hope you tried with high and concurrent loads to test it.

Comment: I did try with high concurrent loads, in a small test case and it looked fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no coordinating of threads or clustered processes, so the question comes down to whether the OS will allow multiple open write streams to a file.  The default C flags for CreateWriteStream are `O_WRONLY || O_CREAT || O_TRUNC`.  This indicates a first problem - all processes will be creating a new truncated file (when probably you wanted appending).

So assuming you're specifying `w+` as a flag when creating the stream...

For Linux, [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154446/is-file-append-atomic-in-unix) indicates that you will be ok as long as number of bytes is less than PIPE_BUF  bytes (4096 on Linux, 512 on some other Unixes).

I'm not sure what the answer is on Windows.

Comment: How do you specifiy the w+ when creating the stream? I am calling fs.createWriteStream(path, [options]) is this a possible option? It isn't listed in the doc. Also, is there a way to change the PIPE_BUF on my systems? I'm using 3 different flavors of unix - macOS, centOS, and ubuntu

Comment: The [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) show an example of using 'w'.  You can just replace that with 'w+'.  Short of editing Linux source code and recompiling, I don't believe there is a way to change PIPE_BUF (it is a compiled-in constant)

Comment: How would you distribute in Node several different files (writing) amongst several threads or processes? I can't find anything after searching around.

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira did you find anything?

Comment: @No_Name yes I did, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73585229/1243247)