# Node.js on multi-core machines for file I/O operations

Tags: node.js, async.js, node-cluster

I'm a bit confused because all the examples I read about Node `cluster` module only seem to apply to webservers and concurrent requests. Otherwise to CPU intensive application it is recommended to use the `worker_threads` module.

And what about I/O file operations? Imagine I have an array with 1 million filenames: `['1.txt', '2.txt', etc., ..., '1000000.txt']` and I need to do heavy processing and then write the result file content?

What would be the method to efficiently use all the cores of the CPU to spread the processing towards different cores amongst different filenames?

Normally I would use this:

```fs
const fs = require('fs')
const fs = require('async')
const heavyProcessing = require('./heavyProcessing.js')

const files = ['1.txt', '2.txt', ..., '1000000.txt']

async.each(files, function (file, cb) {
  fs.writeFile(file, heavyProcessing(file), function (err) {
    if (!err) cb()
  })
}
```

Should I use now the `cluster` or the `worker_threads`? And how should I use it?

Does this work?

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const fs = require('async')
const heavyProcessing = require('./heavyProcessing.js')

const cluster = require('node:cluster');
const http = require('node:http');
const numCPUs = require('node:os').cpus().length;
const process = require('node:process');

if (cluster.isPrimary) {
  console.log(`Primary ${process.pid} is running`);

  // Fork workers.
  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
  });
} else {
  const files = ['1.txt', '2.txt', ..., '1000000.txt']

  async.each(files, function (file, cb) {
    fs.writeFile(file, heavyProcessing(file), function (err) {
      if (!err) cb()
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: This won't do what you want: each process in your cluster will process all your files. If this is a production requirement, it's probably worth your trouble to write code that uses a pool of worker threads.

Comment: @O.Jones would you recommend me any module? What about `piscina`?

Comment: @O.Jones what about this? https://github.com/piscinajs/piscina/issues/270

Comment: I suppose it will work. I've never used it.

Comment: @O.Jones found it, I did this gist explaining it: https://gist.github.com/jfoclpf/325bb925fedf50a9cf96bd00d99e2243

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for everyone to know, if they are interested, you need to use the npm module `piscina`.

In this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jfoclpf/325bb925fedf50a9cf96bd00d99e2243) I explain everything. NodeJS is a powerful tool for backend developers, but you must be aware of multi-core processing in order to maximize the potential of your CPU.
This NodeJS multi-core feature is mostly used for webservers and NodeJS has already out of the box the `cluster` module thereto.
Although NodeJS has also out of the box the module `threads`, it's not so easy to deal with.

Let's create a project that will test single-thread and multi-thread CPU intensive data and write some random data to file.

Create the project:

```
mkdir test-threads && cd test-threads
npm init -y
```

Install dependencies and create `dist/` directory

```
npm install async progress piscina command-line-args
mkdir dist
```

Create the file `index.js` at the root of the project directory

```js
const path = require('path')
const async = require('async')
const ProgressBar = require('progress')
const Piscina = require('piscina')
const commandLineArgs = require('command-line-args')

console.time('main')

const worker = require(path.resolve(__dirname, 'worker.js'))
const piscina = new Piscina({
  filename: path.resolve(__dirname, 'worker.js')
})

const argvOptions = commandLineArgs([
  { name: 'multi-thread', type: Boolean },
  { name: 'iterations', alias: 'i', type: Number }
])

const files = []
for (let i=0; i < (argvOptions.iterations || 1000); i++) {
  files.push(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', i + '.txt'))
}

var bar = new ProgressBar(':bar', { total: files.length, width: 80 });

async.each(files, function (file, cb) {
  (async function() {
    try {
      const err = argvOptions['multi-thread'] ? (await piscina.run(file)) : worker(file)
      bar.tick()
      if (err) cb(Error(err)); else cb()
    } catch(err) {
      cb(Error(err))
    }
  })();
}, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('There was an error: ', err)
    process.exitCode = 1
  } else {
    bar.terminate()
    console.log('Success')
    console.timeEnd('main')
    process.exitCode = 0
  }
})
```

Create now `worker.js` also at the root of the project directory

```js
const fs = require('fs')

// some CPU intensive function; the higher is baseNumber, the higher is the time elapsed
function mySlowFunction(baseNumber) {
  let result = 0
  for (var i = Math.pow(baseNumber, 7); i >= 0; i--) {      
    result += Math.atan(i) * Math.tan(i)
  }
}

module.exports = (file) => {
  try {
    mySlowFunction(parseInt(Math.random() * 10 + 1))
    fs.writeFileSync(file, Math.random().toString())
    return null
  } catch (e) {
    return Error(e)
  }
}
```

Now just run on single thread and check time elapsed, for 1000 and 10000 iterations (one iteration equals to data processing and file creation)

```
node index.js -i 1000
node index.js -i 10000
```

Now compare with the great advantage of multi-thread

```
node index.js --multi-thread -i 1000
node index.js --multi-thread -i 10000
```

With the test I did (16 cores CPU), the difference is huge, it went with 1000 iterations from `1:27.061 (m:ss.mmm)` for single thread to `8.884s` with multi-thread. Check also the files inside `dist/` to be sure they were created correctly.

Comment: An excellent-quality contribution, this is.