# How to perform file-locking on Windows without installing a new package

Tags: python, locking, pywin32, fcntl

I've added [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30407352/how-to-prevent-a-race-condition-when-multiple-processes-attempt-to-write-to-and) to a Python package ([`brian2`](http://brian2.readthedocs.org/en/2.0b3/)) that places an exclusive lock on a file to prevent a race condition.  However, because this code includes calls to `fcntl`, it does not work on Windows.  Is there a way for me to place exclusive locks on files in Windows without installing a new package, like `pywin32`?  (I don't want to add a dependency to `brian2`.)

Comment: Do you have module `msvcrt`?

Comment: @cdarke i don't have it, but do you think that's just because i'm on a unix machine?  does it come standard only on windows machines?

Comment: I would not expect it to be on a UNIX machine - the question is about Windows, isn't it?  I have checked, and it is part of the Python standard library for Windows.  Unfortunately it is difficult to produce portable file locking code because the operations are so different (see my post).

Comment: @cdarke thanks for checking that.  i'm guessing `fcntl` doesn't come with the standard library on windows?

Comment: That's correct, `fcntl` is not bundled with Python 2 or 3 on Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since [msvcrt](https://docs.python.org/2/library/msvcrt.html) is part of the standard library, I assume you have it.  The msvcrt (MicroSoft Visual C Run Time) module only implements a small number of the routines available in the MS RTL, however it does implement file locking.
Here is an example:

```
import msvcrt, os, sys

REC_LIM = 20

pFilename = "rlock.dat"
fh = open(pFilename, "w")

for i in range(REC_LIM):

    # Here, construct data into "line"

    start_pos  = fh.tell()    # Get the current start position   

    # Get the lock - possible blocking call   
    msvcrt.locking(fh.fileno(), msvcrt.LK_RLCK, len(line)+1)
    fh.write(line)            #  Advance the current position
    end_pos = fh.tell()       #  Save the end position

    # Reset the current position before releasing the lock 
    fh.seek(start_pos)        
    msvcrt.locking(fh.fileno(), msvcrt.LK_UNLCK, len(line)+1)
    fh.seek(end_pos)          # Go back to the end of the written record

fh.close()
```

The example shown has a similar function as for `fcntl.flock()`, however the code is very different.  Only exclusive locks are supported.
Unlike `fcntl.flock()` there is no start argument (or whence).  The lock or unlock call only operates on the current file position.  This means that in order to unlock the correct region we have to move the current file position back to where it was before we did the read or write.  Having unlocked, we now have to advance the file position again, back to where we were after the read or write, so we can proceed.

If we unlock a region for which we have no lock then we do not get an error or exception.

Comment: is the lock automatically released when the file is closed?

Comment: @dbliss: I'm not sure, and I don't have a Windows machine handy right now to try it.  The doc does not say, so I would not bet on it.  By the way, I put a demo here: http://darkeside.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/python-msvcrtlocking-trials-and.html

Comment: from what i can tell it is, but i also don't have a windows machine to test this on.