# Python - Simplest solution to deal with multiple write-access to same file

Tags: python, file

I have multiple python scripts which have to write text on same file. Obviously I want to guarantee that data will be consistent and non-overlapped.
Which is the simplest (and most efficient) way to do that?
I don't need cross-platform solution.

Thank you

Comment: How are they writing to the file? Are they each going to be appending to the end, rewriting from the beginning, or randomly somewhere in between? If only appending I don't think there would be an issue

Comment: They have to delete last char, append new text and close the file.
If I use f.open(path,"a+") and f.write("text").
My doubt are about what happens if while script A is writing on file, script B do same? If there isn't a "locker" text could be overlap right?

Comment: You could use a file lock.

Comment: I hoped in a simpler solution, because I haven't platform independent requirements... but it seems to be the only option available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Multiple users append to the same file at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853551/python-multiple-users-append-to-the-same-file-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're on a *nix platform you can create a file lock using the [fcntl](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html). There is also the platform independent [filelock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/filelock), but I've never used that myself.

Using *fcntl* you would lock the file as soon as it was opened, then write, then release the lock.

Comment: It seems what I need. Now I'm trying with
f.open(path,'a')
fcntl.flock(f,LOCK.EX)
f.write("")
fcntl.flock(f,LOCK.UN)
f.close()

But now I have another question... If a script has exclusive access and another one try to obtain the same what happens? I would like it retry continuously in a kind of priority queue... but I think in this way raise just an exception.

Comment: Look at the docs for the underlying flock() call. If using LOCK_NB the call will be non-blocking and will raise an exception in python, otherwise it will block.

Answer (score 0):

Use filelock mudule.

```
from filelock import FileLock

with FileLock("mySharedFile.txt"):
    # your code
    print("Locked.")
```

Answer (score -1):

In the `open(*filename,mode*)` line, just use a as mode. This will make it add the lines you write instead of deleting the old ones

Comment: I'm using this method but it doesn't assure data will be consistent.