# (Python read CSV) Does it make difference to write the code like this or like that?

Tags: python, file, csv

```
from csv import reader
nfl = list(reader(open("nfl.csv")))
```

or like this:

```
import csv
f = open("my_data.csv")
csvreader = csv.reader(f)
my_data = list(csvreader)
```

Does it make much difference if I write a code in a first way? Is it as fast as the second one? How is it written in the real corporate life?

Comment: It probably doesn't use either method, but the second is probably better. You should be using `with` context manager for handling files since that will ensure that the file gets closed at the end. Also, do you want all of the lines in a single list because it might be desirable to iterate through the reader line by line if you don't necessarily want all of the data?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples) gives examples of the correct way of reading CSV files

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar that's a particularly heavy dependency for reading CSV files if the OP doesn't already have `pandas` for some other purpose

Comment: @roganjosh So, I can iterate if I don't want all the data?
But what happens, if the file remains opened? Is there a risk that it might be accidentally edited by someone from aside? Or it just eats PC's memory?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You're talking about concurrent access to a file?

Comment: @roganjosh That's right, is it possible?

Comment: There's an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853551/python-multiple-users-append-to-the-same-file-at-the-same-time) about concurrency and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395542/is-explicitly-closing-files-important) about closing files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither method is ideal because you want to ensure the file is closed at the end. For this purpose you can use `with` to ensure the file is closed once you're finished processing it. This avoids mistakes where you might forget to call `.close()` on the file. More info on context managers can be found [here](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/). Examples of this can be seen in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples).

So, something like:

```
with open('my_data.csv') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    data = list(reader)
```

Note, however, this loads the whole contents of the file into memory. As the documentation examples show, you could instead iterate through the `reader` object if you don't need the whole file in memory.