# concurrent access to file linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, concurrency, filesystems

I was looking at how a syscall read/write was done in linux, and i found this :

```
....
loff_t pos = file_pos_read(f.file);
ret = vfs_read(f.file, buf, count, &pos);
file_pos_write(f.file, pos);
fdput(f);
...`
```

My questions are :

Where did the locking go? I would have imaginated something like :

```
....
lock(f.file);  // <-- lock file struct
loff_t pos = file_pos_read(f.file);
ret = vfs_read(f.file, buf, count, &pos);
file_pos_write(f.file, pos);
fdput(f);
unlock(f.file);  // <-- unlock file struct
...
```

If multiple threads try to read/write at the same time, they could read/write at the same offset ?

If my understanding is correct, linux doesn't use any locking mechanism to protect the offset, is this POSIX compliant ?

I did look at the POSIX specification, and found nothing about this case.

Comment: this is user space code?

Comment: @Sibrajas: read and write are syscalls, which means that their implementation is inside the kernel. (well with the exception of vdso and vsyscalls, but dont worry about that)

Comment: May be this link on mandatory locking is useful. http://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/mandatory-locking.txt

Comment: @user1131467 yes.i know that. i was just misguided with this text. how a syscall read/write was done(in first line). It could be edited as implemented.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are POSIX' read() and write() system calls atomic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417806/are-posix-read-and-write-system-calls-atomic)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Linux doesn't use any locking mechanism to protect multithread writing to a file.

You have to use your own mutex to protect your file.

Comment: Is this how posix specfied it ? Does all UNIX kernels do the same ?

Answer (score 4):

It's your responsibility in a multithreaded application to serialize access to file descriptors.  Across processes you can use the `flock(2)` syscall to synchronize access to the same file.

The kernel won't crash if you access the same file from two different processes/threads, but it may overwrite or corrupt the file position and file data in an undefined way.