# Is this file operation thread safe?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I was wondering the thread safety of my PRINT macro and wrote a program to see if file operations in my situation is thread safe, so I added sleep in fn0 and found to be thread safe.

```
$cat t
fn1
fn0
```

prints both and doesnt overwrite.

Is the test good enough or are there other situations 
PS : Iam not sharing file pointers 
Iam happy with the ordering though (unordered / non sequenced is fine ) Iam only interested in corruption/overwriting - it seems like the file pointer is moved well.

-----------macro-------------

```
#define PRINT(args ...) if (logflag) { \
FILE *flog = fopen(LOGFILE, "a"); \
fprintf( flog, args); \
fclose(flog); \
}  fprintf(stderr, args); fflush(stderr);
```

-------------------test prog----------------------------

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define LOGFILE "t"
char c='1';
void *fn0(void* v)
{

    FILE *flog = fopen(LOGFILE, "a");
    //sleep(2);
    fprintf( flog,"%s\n", "fn0");
    fclose(flog);

    printf ("Enter value ");
    c=getchar();
}

void* fn1(void*v)
{
    FILE *flog = fopen(LOGFILE, "a");
    fprintf( flog,"%s\n", "fn1");
    fclose(flog);
}
int main()
{
    pthread_t t0;
    pthread_t t1;


    pthread_create(&t0, NULL, fn0, (void *) NULL);
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, fn1, (void *) NULL);
    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t0, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Short answer: there is no way to determine which order "fn1" and "fn0" is printed.

Comment: Iam happy with the ordering though

Comment: Depending on the sharing rules, you may well get the problems David Herrernan is referring to - you can't open the file at the same time from two threads - it may work, or it may not, depending on what OS and what the rules are. I'm also pretty sure that it's not guaranteed that your data will be flushed to disk consistently. In short, no it's not guaranteed to work. Certainly writing from two threads to the same file using the same handle will can "mess up" if you try hard enough [and sods law says that it's when you need it to be correct most, that it goes wrong]

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not threadsafe. If one of the threads attempts to open the file whilst the other thread has it open, the second attempt to open may fail with a sharing violation. Even if the OS allows you to open the file twice, simultaneously, you now have two separate unsynchronized buffers, and two distinct file pointers. There's absolutely no guarantee that your writes will be consistent.

You should serialize access to the shared resource with a mutex.

Alternatively, use a producer/consumer approach and put all writing to the log on a single thread, the consumer. Then let multiple producer threads push logging tasks onto the consumer thread.

Comment: it doesnt look like it 'cat t' always prints both fn names.

Comment: You can't prove thread safety by writing a trivial example and finding that it behaves when you run it a couple of times. Races and deadlocks don't always manifest.

Comment: I totally agree with your answer, but want to point out that "*... a couple of times.*" could easily mean thousands of thousands of times! ;-)

Comment: @alk yes you are correct, Iam looking for a test/simulation case [ in my case Iam introducing sleep to simulate the race(context switch). [I know it depends on the system etc.,] what else can i do to simulate

Comment: No test case can ever prove that your code is threadsafe. You have to prove it from static analysis. A test case can demonstrate that it is not threadsafe, but can never prove the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

That code is pretty close to being thread-safe.  It is certainly thread-safe by the fact that it will not:

- corrupt the process memory
- lead to segfaults due to simultaneuos access of in-memory data structures.
- lead to reads of partially written data (such as filling a buffer in one thread and reading in another thread at the same time)

However, as mentioned by David Heffeman, it is not thread-safe at the level of writing to file.  It is close though.  Using system calls to write instead of buffered IO, such as using open + write instead of fopen + fwrite, can be used to get atomic writes and thread-safety.

See this answer for more details on making sure writes are atomic:
[Is file append atomic in UNIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154446/is-file-append-atomic-in-unix)

One other thing; the use of global `char c` is risky, although it's use is thread-safe in the context shown.  If `c` were declared inside the function `fn0`, it would eliminate potential issues (as long as it were kept an automatic variable and were not declared `static`).

On the topic of testing cases like these -- in my experience, stress testing can give reliable results, but it takes some effort to stress test - and stress tests usually bring out all kinds of nuances, which are great to fix, but can be overwhelming and frutstrating.  In order to stress test, just setup a program that spins off a configurable number of threads over a configurable number of iterations.  I recommend starting with 20 threads and 1000 iterations for a test like this.

With that said, I agree that thread-safety and race conditions can never be 100% proven not to exist through testing alone.

Comment: Until recently... man 2 write: Among the APIs subsequently listed are write() and writev(2).  And among the effects that should be atomic across threads (and processes) are updates of the file offset.  However, on Linux before version 3.14, this was not the case: if two processes that share an open file description (see open(2)) perform a write() (or writev(2)) at the same time, then the I/O operations were not atomic with respect updating the file offset, with  the  result  that the blocks of data output by the two processes might (incorrectly) overlap.  This problem was fixed in Linux 3.14.