# Is nodejs file stream safe in cluster enviroment?

Tags: node.js

When I use nodejs with cluster module,
does following code mess up file contents?

```
if (!cluster.isMaster) {    
    var stream = fs.createWriteStream('samefile.txt', {flags: 'a'});
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
        stream.write('... big string ... \n');
}
```

I tested, but line was not mixed.

But I couldn't find document or base about file stream's cluster safety.

Comment: Your following code looks totally clean.

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"?  Writing to the same file from multiple processes without any central coordination will either have file locking or concurrency issues - one or the other.

Comment: @jfriend00 maybe I asked question similar with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154446/is-file-append-atomic-in-unix/24270790#24270790 I want to know that "append mode" guarantee atomicity in nodejs file stream.

Comment: Is that other question the same thing you intend to ask here?