# Why O_APPEND is atomic

Tags: file, unix, io

I learned that O_APPEND is atomic, and from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154446/is-file-append-atomic-in-unix) I knew that O_APPEND is atomic when size below PIPE_BUF.

But, why? Before write append, the current file offset must be updated to the end of file, how to graduate the two operation is atomic?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Ultimately using locks or similar mutual exclusion facilities. Basically the write in append mode is submitted as a single operation to the kernel which then provides the necessary interlocks to insure that the operation on the same file are indivisible. Beware that the atomicity is more of a best-effort service and may fail for network file-systems and the like.

Comment: @doynax Thanks a lot !