# Does python logging support multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have been told that logging can not be used in Multiprocessing. You have to do the concurrency control in case multiprocessing messes the log.

But I did some test, it seems like there is no problem using logging in multiprocessing

```
import time
import logging
from multiprocessing import Process, current_process, pool


# setup log
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(filename)s[line:%(lineno)d] %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S',
                    filename='/tmp/test.log',
                    filemode='w')


def func(the_time, logger):
    proc = current_process()
    while True:
        if time.time() >= the_time:
            logger.info('proc name %s id %s' % (proc.name, proc.pid))
            return



if __name__ == '__main__':

    the_time = time.time() + 5

    for x in xrange(1, 10):
        proc = Process(target=func, name=x, args=(the_time, logger))
        proc.start()
```

As you can see from the code.

I deliberately let the subprocess write log at the same moment( 5s after start) to increase the chance of conflict. But there are no conflict at all.

So my question is can we use logging in multiprocessing?
Why so many posts say we can not ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As Matino correctly explained: logging in a multiprocessing setup is not safe, as multiple processes (who do not know anything about the other ones existing) are writing into the same file, potentially intervening with each other.

Now what happens is that every process holds an open file handle and does an "append write" into that file. The question is under what circumstances the append write is "atomic" (that is, cannot be interrupted by e.g. another process writing to the same file and intermingling his output). This problem applies to every programming language, as in the end they'll do a syscall to the kernel. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154446/is-file-append-atomic-in-unix) answers under which circumstances a shared log file is ok.

It comes down to checking your pipe buffer size, on linux that is defined in `/usr/include/linux/limits.h` and is 4096 bytes. For other OSes you find [here](http://ar.to/notes/posix#pipe-buf) a good list.

That means: If your log line is less than 4'096 bytes (if on Linux), then the append is safe, if the disk is directly attached (i.e. no network in between). But for more details please check the first link in my answer. To test this you can do `logger.info('proc name %s id %s %s' % (proc.name, proc.pid, str(proc.name)*5000))` with different lenghts. With 5000 for instance I got already mixed up log lines in `/tmp/test.log`.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641420/how-should-i-log-while-using-multiprocessing-in-python) there are already quite a few solutions to this, so I won't add my own solution here.

**Update: Flask and multiprocessing**

> Web frameworks like flask will be run in multiple workers if hosted by uwsgi or nginx. In that case, multiple processes may write into one log file. Will it have problems?

The error handling in flask is done via stdout/stderr which is then cought by the webserver (uwsgi, nginx, etc.) which needs to take care that logs are written in correct fashion (see e.g. [this flask+nginx example](http://flaviusim.com/blog/Deploying-Flask-with-nginx-uWSGI-and-Supervisor/)), probably also adding process information so you can associate error lines to processes. From [flasks doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/errorhandling/#logging-to-a-file):

> By default as of Flask 0.11, errors are logged to your webserver’s log automatically. Warnings however are not.

So you'd still have this issue of intermingled log files if you use `warn` and the message exceeds the pipe buffer size.

Comment: One more question. Web frameworks like flask will be run in multiple workers if hosted by uwsgi or nginx. In that  case, multiple processes may write into one log file. Will it have problem?

Comment: @KramerLi: I've answered your question under a new section in my answer

Answer (score 25):

It is not safe to write to a single file from multiple processes.

According to https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes

> Although logging is thread-safe, and logging to a single file from
>   multiple threads in a single process is supported, logging to a single
>   file from multiple processes is not supported, because there is no
>   standard way to serialize access to a single file across multiple
>   processes in Python.

One possible solution would be to have each process write to its own file. You can achieve this by writing your own handler that adds process pid to the end of the file:

```
import logging.handlers
import os


class PIDFileHandler(logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler):

    def __init__(self, filename, mode='a', encoding=None, delay=0):
        filename = self._append_pid_to_filename(filename)
        super(PIDFileHandler, self).__init__(filename, mode, encoding, delay)

    def _append_pid_to_filename(self, filename):
        pid = os.getpid()
        path, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
        return '{0}-{1}{2}'.format(path, pid, extension)
```

Then you just need to call `addHandler`:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('foo')
fh = PIDFileHandler('bar.log')
logger.addHandler(fh)
```

Comment: Well.. I would appreciate this if I could make it work, but not sure... where should the logger be defined (in which scope) and how should it be passed to the individual subprocesses?

Answer (score 3):

Use a queue for correct handling of concurrency simultaneously recovering from errors by feeding everything to the parent process via a pipe.

```
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
import multiprocessing, threading, logging, sys, traceback

class MultiProcessingLog(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, name, mode, maxsize, rotate):
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)

        self._handler = RotatingFileHandler(name, mode, maxsize, rotate)
        self.queue = multiprocessing.Queue(-1)

        t = threading.Thread(target=self.receive)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    def setFormatter(self, fmt):
        logging.Handler.setFormatter(self, fmt)
        self._handler.setFormatter(fmt)

    def receive(self):
        while True:
            try:
                record = self.queue.get()
                self._handler.emit(record)
            except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
                raise
            except EOFError:
                break
            except:
                traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stderr)

    def send(self, s):
        self.queue.put_nowait(s)

    def _format_record(self, record):
         # ensure that exc_info and args
         # have been stringified.  Removes any chance of
         # unpickleable things inside and possibly reduces
         # message size sent over the pipe
        if record.args:
            record.msg = record.msg % record.args
            record.args = None
        if record.exc_info:
            dummy = self.format(record)
            record.exc_info = None

        return record

    def emit(self, record):
        try:
            s = self._format_record(record)
            self.send(s)
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            raise
        except:
            self.handleError(record)

    def close(self):
        self._handler.close()
        logging.Handler.close(self)
```

The handler does all the file writing from the parent process and uses just one thread to receive messages passed from child processes

Comment: It would also be nice to see the usage example of this class.

Comment: Yes, could you please provide an example

Comment: This answer seems to be copy-paste from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/894284/3015186). Note that this will not work on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

[`QueueHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.QueueHandler) is native in Python 3.2+, and safely handles multiprocessing logging.

Python docs have two complete examples: [Logging to a single file from multiple processes](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes)

For those using Python < 3.2, just copy `QueueHandler` into your own code from: https://gist.github.com/vsajip/591589 or alternatively import [logutils](https://pypi.org/project/logutils/).

Each process (including the parent process) puts its logging on the `Queue`, and then a `listener` thread or process (one example is provided for each) picks those up and writes them all to a file - no risk of corruption or garbling.

Note: this question is basically a duplicate of [How should I log while using multiprocessing in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/641420/3427777) so I've copied my answer from that question as I'm pretty sure it's currently the best solution.