# python3.6 multiprocessing logging

Tags: python-3.x, logging, multiprocessing

I looked at its code, somewhat puzzled.
[Does python logging support multiprocessing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47968861/does-python-logging-support-multiprocessing)

**Environment**

> python 3.6.6
>
> logging 0.5.1.2

**Test code**

```
import time
import logging
from multiprocessing import Process, current_process, pool

print(logging.__version__)
# setup log
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(filename)s[line:%(lineno)d] %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S',
                    filename='test.log',
                    filemode='w')


def func(the_time, logger):
    proc = current_process()
    while True:
        if time.time() >= the_time:
            logger.info('proc name %s id %s %s' % (proc.name, proc.pid, str(proc.name)*5000))
            return



if __name__ == '__main__':

    the_time = time.time() + 5

    for x in range(1, 10):
        proc = Process(target=func, name=x, args=(the_time, logger))
        proc.start()
```

**Problem**

> use Python 3.6.6, multiprocess writes to the same file without
>   confusion.
>
> if you use Python 2.7 causes confusion.
>
> If you know the problem, please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No matter the Python version, the different processes should write without synchronization so there should be clobbered records.

Python does not resolve this automatically for you but it has the tools to help.

In Python 3, use [QueueHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#queuehandler) and [QueueListener](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#queuelistener).

In Python 2 or 3, use [multiprocessing-logging](https://pypi.org/project/multiprocessing-logging/) which works only on Linux.