# python logging RotatingFileHandler and TimedRotatingFileHandler is not working with queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

- New logging packages (RotatingFileHandler & TimedRotatingFileHandler)
     is not working as per expectation.

  problem: It creates the number of files as much defined by the
     user(backupCount) without completing its maxBytes limit.

  It creates any size of the file even if the user defines
     maxBytes(file size could be in 10kb 34B etc.)

  It sends log anywhere in any file it's too random.

file1: #For adding in queue

```
import redis 
from newTesting1 import executeJobQueue
import json
import time
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
conn = redis.Redis('127.0.0.1')
def addInQueue(queueName, PartnerId, CompanyName):
    newQ = Queue(queueName, connection=conn)
    for i in range(1000):
        newQ.enqueue(executeJobQueue, str(json.dumps({"ObjectId":"", 
                       "DisplayName":"", "FirstName":"", "LastName":"", 
                       "UserPrincipalName":"", "IsLicensed":"", 
                       "Licenses":"", "City":""})))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.start()
    scheduler.add_job(addInQueue, 'cron', ["syncDirectoryQueue", None, None], month='*', day='*', hour='10', minute='12')
    while True:
        time.sleep(3000)
```

File 2: Processing from queue

```
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection
import redis
conn = redis.Redis('127.0.0.1')
import logging.handlers
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('MyLogger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler("/Users/SMishra/log/application", maxBytes=100000, backupCount=10)
logger.addHandler(handler)

def executeJobQueue(newEntry):
    rq = Queue('syncDirectoryQueue', connection=conn)
    logger.info("executing queue %s %s", newEntry, len(rq))
    logger.info("executing queue %s %s", newEntry, len(rq))
    logger.info("executing queue %s %s", newEntry, len(rq))
    logger.info("executing queue %s %s", newEntry, len(rq))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Connection(conn):
        worker = Worker(list(map(Queue, ['syncDirectoryQueue'])))
        worker.work()
```

output:

---

1. -rw-r--r--  1 SMishra  staff   1.2K Dec 23 10:13 application.10
   -rw-r--r--  1 SMishra  staff   1.2K Dec 23 10:13 application.9
   -rw-r--r--  1 SMishra  staff   1.2K Dec 23 10:13 application.8
   -rw-r--r--  1 SMishra  staff   1.2K Dec 23 10:13 application.7
   -rw-r--r--  1 SMishra  staff   1.2K Dec 23 10:13 application.6
   -rw-r--r--  1 SMishra  staff   1.2K Dec 23 10:13 application.5
   -rw-r--r--  1 SMishra  staff   1.2K Dec 23 10:13 application.4
   -rw-r--r--  1 SMishra  staff   1.2K Dec 23 10:13 application.3
   -rw-r--r--  1 SMishra  staff   1.2K Dec 23 10:13 application.2
   -rw-r--r--  1 SMishra  staff   632B Dec 23 10:13 application
   -rw-r--r--  1 SMishra  staff   1.2K Dec 23 10:13 application.1

---

Comment: Hey Satyam and welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please show us some code that you used?

Comment: Hey, @GenericNerd Nerd Thank you for replay. I have added the code please see. I am looking forward for your answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does python logging support multiprocessing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47968861/does-python-logging-support-multiprocessing)

Comment: Hey buran, But the same issue was not there in python2.7