# How to implement writing transaction on linux? Write all or do nothing

Tags: linux, transactions, diskspace

I need to write `bytes1` to `file1` and `bytes2` to `file2` and to make sure  I will not catch `no space left` exception during writings.

Or maybe someone knows how sql databases implement integrity of their files?

Comment: this is called "atomic writes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to implement transaction but don't know pitfalls of this method. The key element is [truncate](https://linux.die.net/man/2/truncate) syscall which will allow us to implement a rollback logic. Here is a pseudocode:

```
file1Pos = file1.tell()
file2Pos = file2.tell()

err = file1.write(bytes1)
if err != nil {
    // rollback to previous position
    file1.truncate(file1Pos)
    // The file offset is not changed after truncation
    file1.seek(file1Pos, SEEK_SET)
}

err = file2.write(bytes2)
if err != nil {
    file1.truncate(file1Pos)
    file1.seek(file1Pos, SEEK_SET)

    file2.truncate(file2Pos)
    file2.seek(file2Pos, SEEK_SET)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Is file append atomic in UNIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154446/is-file-append-atomic-in-unix) a single write is atomic on linux if the file is opened with `O_DIRECT` .  There might be more developments out there if you search for "atomic write".