# Why doesn't my multi-process writing program trigger concurrent conflict?

Tags: c, linux, concurrency, multiprocess

I'm trying to trigger some concurrent conflicts by having several processes writing to the same file, but couldn't:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void concurrent_write()
{
    int create_fd = open("bar.txt", O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
    close(create_fd);
    int repeat = 20;
    int num = 4;

    for (int process = 0; process < num; process++)
    {
        int rc = fork();
        if (rc == 0)
        {
            // child
            int write_fd = open("bar.txt", O_WRONLY | O_APPEND, 0644);
            for (int idx = 0; idx < repeat; idx++)
            {
                sleep(1);
                write(write_fd, "child writing\n", strlen("child writing\n"));
            }
            close(write_fd);

            exit(0);
        }
    }

    for (int process = 0; process < num; process++)
    {
        wait(NULL);
        // wait for all children to exits
    }

    printf("write to `bar.txt`\n%d lines written by %d process\n", repeat * num, num);

    printf("wc:");
    if (fork() == 0)
    {
        // child
        char *args[3];
        args[0] = strdup("wc");
        args[1] = strdup("bar.txt");
        args[2] = NULL;
        execvp(args[0], args);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    concurrent_write();

    return 0;
}
```

This program fork `#num` children and then have all of them write `#repeat` lines to a file. But every time (however I change `#repeat` and `#num`) I got the same result that the length of `bar.txt` (output file) matched the number of total written lines. Why is there no concurrent conflicts triggered?

Comment: Are you only testing for the number of lines ? If so, I wouldn't expect it to change even if individual characters get mixed up.

Comment: @gchapuis I don't get it

Comment: What I mean is, even if your lines get mixed up by concurrent writes, I would still expect the same number of \n in the files.

Comment: Oh that I didn't expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing to a file can be divided into a two-step process:

1. Locate where you want to write.
2. Write data into the file.

You open a file with flag `O_APPEND` and it ensures that the two-step process is atomic. So, you can always find the lines of the file as the count you set.

Answer (score 1):

See the [`open(2)` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html):

> O_APPEND
>
> The file is opened in append mode.  Before each write(2),
> the file offset is positioned at the end of the file, as
> if with lseek(2).  **The modification of the file offset and
> the write operation are performed as a single atomic step.**

In essence, one of the major design features of `O_APPEND` is precisely to prevent the sort of "concurrent conflicts" you mention.  The typical example would be a log file that several processes must write to.  Using `O_APPEND` ensures their messages do not overwrite each other.

Moreover, all data written by a single `write` call is written atomically, so provided that your `write("child writing\n")` successfully writes all its bytes (which for a regular file it usually would), they will not be interleaved with the bytes of any other such message.

Answer (score 0):

First, `write()` calls with the `O_APPEND` flag should be atomic.  [Per POSIX `write()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/write.html):

> If the `O_APPEND` flag of the file status flags is set, the file offset shall be set to the end of the file prior to each write and no intervening file modification operation shall occur between changing the file offset and the write operation.

But that's not enough when there are multiple threads or processes making parallel `write()` calls on the same file - that does not guarantee that parallel `write()` calls are atomic.

POSIX does guarantee that [parallel `write()` calls are also atomic](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_07):

> All of the following functions shall be atomic with respect to each
> other in the effects specified in POSIX.1-2017 when they operate on
> regular files or symbolic links:
>
> ```
> ...
>
> write()
>
> ...
> ```

See also [**Is file append atomic in UNIX?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154446/is-file-append-atomic-in-unix)

Beware, though.  Reading that question and its answers shows that Linux filesystems such as `ext3` are not POSIX compliant once you get past a relatively small size operation, or possibly if you cross page and/or file system sector boundaries.  I suspect XFS and ZFS will support `write()` atomicity much better given their origins.

And none of this applies to Windows.