Facing issue with flask server where one of the endpoints writes to a common file
For some reasons, I cannot post the actual code; I will try my best to explain the issue I am facing clearly.
In my dev setup, I am running ansible play to configure 3 or more nodes.
Also, locally I am running flask server app which has few endpoints and one of them is for writing to a "common file".
One of the ansible tasks is delegated to local_host. This task runs multiple times (depending on number of target hosts) on localhost and calls flask server by invoking the endpoint that writes to a common file. Here is where I see 500: Server internal error occasionally.
I do understand that writing to a common file from multiple process/thread could lead to potential errors. I have read using sqlite3 DB for such scenarios.
This is development setup and I need to understand what is the issue with flask server that I am seeing the error in first place before trying to fix the issue (possibly without sqlite3).
Note that the common_file is not a huge file by any stretch and the data to be written (through ansible tasks) is also small

If you see a server error, inspect the server logs. Turn on debugging options if applicable. I'm sorry, but everything else is just a speculation.

Regarding the multiple writes to a file: If you are just appending, the worst case should be intermixed output, but even that can be avoided for small chunks: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1154599/5378816


I do understand that writing to a common file from multiple(...)thread could lead to potential errors.

Right, writing to file-handle created by open is not thread-safe.

Note that the common_file is not a huge file by any stretch and the
data to be written (through ansible tasks) is also small

Trouble is caused by multiple writings to file at once, not by size of what is written.

I have read using sqlite3 DB for such scenarios.

This is one of, but not sole, way of coping with that. Other alternative is using logging from standard library, as

The logging module is intended to be thread-safe without any special
work needing to be done by its clients. It achieves this though using
threading locks; there is one lock to serialize access to the module’s
shared data, and each handler also creates a lock to serialize access
to its underlying I/O.

Simple example, let textsaver.py content be
import logging
from flask import Flask

logger = logging.getLogger('savedtexts')
logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('savedtexts.log'))
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/<text>")
def textsaver(text):
    logger.critical(text)
    return text

then
python -m flask --app textsaver run

will run development server, collecting text, e.g. after visiting

http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello
http://127.0.0.1:5000/world

content of savedtexts.log will be
hello
world


Could this situation be the exact reason I see server internal error very rarely?
Just want to make sure if I am not overlooking any other issue.
